# Find occurence of substring in string using indexOf and substring in java

Tags: java

Why this code always return `true`?

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    String prefix = str.substring(0,n-1);
    int index = str.indexOf(prefix,n-1);
    return index != -1;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: To `true`? I would not expect that from this code. Please make a MCVE. This code finds the first index, of the first `n-1` characters of a String, but starting at index `n-1`. Essentially, if it returns `true`, then the first `n-1` characters are repeated next to each other in the string. But is that the intention here?

Comment: Note that your if/else block is equivalent to `return index != -1;` which is probably more readable.

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing?

Comment: I'm working through the codingBat problems..This problem is listed under http://codingbat.com/prob/p136417 
"Given a string, consider the prefix string made of the first N chars of the string. Does that prefix string appear somewhere else in the string? Assume that the string is not empty and that N is in the range 1..str.length()."

Comment: @Tunaki: Exactly!
@ Assylias: You are right but then the codes still evaluates always to true.
@ Akash: the parameters are defined by the codingBat environment

Comment: But what is the question?!

Comment: @Tunaki Why does the code always return true? Because str.indexOf(prefix,n-1) should search the String str for occurences of the substring prefix starting at index n-1 But even if there are no such strings found the code always return true..What am I missing?

Comment: If you try with `prefixAgain("plop plap", 5)` (or any index for that matter), it won't return `true`...

Comment: @Tunaki: Probably, but I cannot choose the String str which is passed to the method prefixAgain. The str is choosen by the codingBat environment. The code must then generate the prefix using the first n characters (starting at index 0). Then the code should detect further occurences of that prefix in the remaining string, i.e. starting from index n-1..

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work better for you:

```
int index = str.indexOf(prefix,0);
```

You were trying to find the index of the prefix at the end of where you were looking (n-1). What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com;
public class Mycode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(prefixAgain("nishikantnishikant", 11));
        /* false - if you have repeated string it will return false
           until index is greater than length of the string */

        System.out.println(prefixAgain("nishikant", 3));
        /* False - if there is no repeat, you can get false */

        System.out.println(prefixAgain("nishikant", 2));
        /* true */

        System.out.println(prefixAgain("nishikantnishikant", 10));
        /* true - if you have repeated string it will return true
           until index is equal to length of the string */
    }
    public static  boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
        String prefix = str.substring(0,n-1);
        int index = str.indexOf(prefix,n-1);
        return index != -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that I have to use n insted of n-1 in the code. 
This is because the substring method has two different conventions for start and end index.

`str.substring(0,n)` includes the start index (0) but excludes the end index (n). This intuitively makes sense because as such the length of the substring matches n.

Comment: Standard practice for java is for ranges to be semi closed `[int start, int finish)`.  You may want to keep this in mind when developing your own applications which have ranges.